# authorize asp.net core web api (entity framework core) with google oauth

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi, google-oauth

I'm developing an android + web app that consuming the same rest api, that i built using asp.net core and entity framework.

**it works like this:**

1. the user sign in with google to the app
2. the api checks its role
3. api requests is done by rest library (for example, retrofit in android).

so far so good... the problem starts when I'm looking for a way to authorize the api.

**I want (one of) the following:**

1. user can't access the api without web / android app
2. user can't access api calls he's not authorized to make (like creating and deleting...)
3. user can't access api calls for entities that are not related to him (for example, shop owner can only make api calls that related to it's shop.)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use jwt authentication to secure your api.

Here is the best reference: 
https://medium.com/net-core-api-jwt-authentication/net-core-api-jwt-authentication-380adcbee705

None of the user will not able to use api if they are not authorized.